# Black Box on google map- please help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, drop-down-menu, slider

I have problem in google map. Iam using drop down menu above google map which slide on mouse come over the item like (Transportation,Education) throw using onmouseover event in javascript .But when the mouse get out of box which mean on mouse out of the box the box become black.
I dont know why this problem happened.
This is an image of problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtL1v.png

This is dropdown list code

```
// Copyright 2006-2007 javascript-array.com

var timeout = 500;
var closetimer  = 0;
var ddmenuitem  = 0;

// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.display = 'none';

    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';
    ddmenuitem.style.display = '';
    ddmenuitem.style.overflowY = 'auto';
    ddmenuitem.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
    ddmenuitem.style.maxHeight = '250px';


}
// close showed layer
function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem){ ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ddmenuitem.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
}
}

// go close timer
function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
    //ddmenuitem.style.zIndex = '1';
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;

    }
}

// close layer when click-out
document.onclick = setTimeout(mclose,5000);
```

This is Sample Code from dropdown html code

```
<ul id="sddm" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <li><a href="#"
        onmouseover="mopen('museumCategory')"
        onmouseout="mclosetime()">Museums</a>
        <div id="museumCategory" style="z-index:1;"
            onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()"
            onmouseout="mclosetime()">
            <tmpl_var name=museumCategory>
        </div>
    </li>
.
.
.
.
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

which plugin you are using.if direct google API, u can try this.google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

Comment: Or check this link If you're using Google Maps v2.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GMap2 and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

Comment: thank you fro your response but where I can put the code which you provide this.google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

Comment: you have a map object know..that object will be placed inside the trigger function.

Comment: could u please share ur code that what you tried.Because the issues might be your height and width of the map container. not enough to carry the google map i think...please check it out...which api u r using.. gmap3 ?